# Ruby: reading two files

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a 9,000+ line CSV file traffic.csv that contains information about traffic through a firewall.
I have a second 400-line text file myhosts.txt that contains my hosts.

I want to search for my hosts (second file) in the fields 'src-hostclass' and 'dst-hostclass'.

My first attempt:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'csv'
hostclass = ARGV[0]

# Load file
csv_fname = ARGV[1]

csv_text = File.open(csv_fname)
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true )

  temp = csv.find {|row| row['src-hostclass'] == hostclass }
  puts temp if temp
  temp = csv.find {|row| row['dst-hostclass'] == hostclass }
  puts temp if temp
```

(The "puts temp if temp" is so empty lines won't be printed.  Is there a better way to do this?)

I then call the ruby program like so:

```
for i in `cat myhosts.txt` ; do ./findhosts.rb $i traffic.csv ; done
```

This works, but is pretty slow.

What would be the best way to change my script so that it reads both files at once instead?

I tried to read both files and then searching in memory, but this doesn't work (nothing is found):

```
require 'csv'

# Load all hosts
hostclasses = File.open(ARGV[0], "r")

# Load CSV file
csv_fname = ARGV[1]

csv_text = File.open(csv_fname)
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true )

hostclasses.each do |hostclass|
  temp = csv.find {|row| row['src-hostclass'] == hostclass }
  puts temp if temp
  temp = csv.find {|row| row['dst-hostclass'] == hostclass }
  puts temp if temp
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Update 5/19/2015: As suggested, I changed and simplified my program:

```
require 'csv'
require 'set'

hostclasses = File.readlines(ARGV[0]).to_set

csv_text = File.open(ARGV[1])
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true )

results = csv.filter {|row| hostclasses.member?(row['src-hostclass']) || hostclasses.member?(row['dst-hostclass']) }
```

But running this results in

```
program.rb:9:in `<main>': undefined method `filter' for #<CSV::Table mode:col_or_row row_count:10> (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: using threads probably...

Comment: @Fredrik_Nyman: Updating your question with an answer is frowned upon, especially after you've accepted the answer, and this question has morphed enough that it deserves a new question. I would recommend opening a new question and then just referencing the old question with a link.

Comment: Yeah, originally this question was just about optimizing existing code to run faster.  Now, since you want to change its behavior, that really should be a new question.

Comment: Thanks for the etiquette note -- much appreciated.  The reason I edited my original post is that I ran out of room in the comment box, and the only other option was to 'Answer' my question, which wouldn't let me comment, just tag the post.  Big thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are executing your Ruby program 400 times, once for each host.  Instead, try making the program more flexible so you can just execute it once.  That way, it only needs to parse that 9000-line CSV file once.  You could read `myhosts.txt` with Ruby instead of with a Bash script.

Another problem is that you are iterating through the 9000-line CSV file to locate rows using `Array#find`.  This will take O(N) time, which might be slow in this case.  Instead, you should use an [index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index) so you can efficiently look up rows in O(log(N)) time.  A simple Ruby hash is a fine type of index to use.

Here is a script I came up with and tested:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'csv'

raise if ARGV.size != 2
hosts_fname, csv_fname = ARGV

row_by_src = {}
row_by_dst = {}
CSV.foreach(csv_fname, headers: true) do |row|
  row_by_src[row['src-hostclass']] = row
  row_by_dst[row['dst-hostclass']] = row
end

File.foreach(hosts_fname) do |host|
  host = host.chomp
  s = row_by_src[host] and puts s
  d = row_by_dst[host] and puts d
end
```

Comment: One limitation of this script is that it only finds the first occurrence of a host.  What do I need to do to find all occurrences?

Comment: I think my answer behaves the same as your original script.  But you can read the hosts first and store them in a Set, like b4hand's answer.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not that you need to read two files at a time, but rather that you read the same file multiple times in your shell loop. Instead, you should read the CSV file once and build a Set that contains all of your hostnames. Then print out all the lines in a single pass.

```
require 'csv'
require 'set'

hostclasses = File.readlines('myhosts.txt').to_set
results = CSV.foreach(ARGV[1], headers: true) do |row|
  puts row['src-hostclass'] if hostclasses.member?(row['src-hostclass'])
  puts row['dst-hostclass'] if hostclasses.member?(row['dst-hostclass'])
end
```

Comment: The to_set method gives me an undefined method error with both Ruby 1.9.1 and Ruby 2.2.1.

Comment: I updated my answer since filter is actually a class method on `CSV` and not an instance method. I wrote the prior version while I was on the bus and couldn't verify it. I've tested the above version, and it seems to work.